# Should I set the title attribute for content DIV's to explain what they contain?

Tags: seo

I have a number of DIV's that break up a page into logical elements for styles and positioning, etc.

As part of optimizing my site for search engine spiders, should I include a title attribute within these DIV's?

(Yes I have a title as part of the whole page, I'm curious on individual structual elements)

Ex

```
...
<div id="SearchOptions" title="Search filters and options - Type in a name or pick a business and Click 'Search' to get started" >
  ....
</div>
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the title doesn't really help or harm SEO since Google does not use it, normally the title will be used to label links but doesn't necessary mean you can't use it on other elements that are not links as it still validates using W3C.

> [**Source**](http://www.searchenginejournal.com/how-to-use-link-title-attribute-correctly/7687/)
>
> Link TITLE attribute for SEO: title attribute carries no weight on
>   search engines (per my experience and based on other SEO’s opinion).
>
> A couple of years ago, Googlers confirmed they did not use TITLE
>   attribute in the algorithm because it was used too seldom.

Normally however `title=""` is normally associated with enhancing the user experience by enabling more detailed hover overs etc, but as I said if these elements are made viewable without a hover over, i.e a JavaScript then the words and content found in the title will be ignored. If you want this content taken into consideration then you would want to use something like:

```
<div id="SearchOptions">
    <div class="hidden-hover">
        <p>I am hidden content on hovers or other JavaScript triggers! I also gracefully is unhidden when JavaScript is disabled.</p>
    </div>
    <p>I am the content of the Search Options</p>
</div>
```